# Buffer Array Usage in C

Tags: c, arrays

My mind tells me there is something wrong here, like maybe I won't be able to append a value to the last element in the array, or it will exceed the UINT8 when doing the cbuf_length++ and crash?  My mind thinks something is wrong, but i just can't see what it is. What is the best way to use arrays that will allow me to append to all 256 elements in the array without crashing or confusing the next programmer?

```
#define CBUF_SIZE 256 
static UINT8 cbuf[CBUF_SIZE];
static UINT8 cbuf_length;

void CBUF_AppendChar(char c)
{
    if (cbuf_length < CBUF_SIZE) { 
        cbuf[cbuf_length] = c;
        cbuf_length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is valid code, but not sensible functionality as a buffer empty and buffer full both are `cbuf_length==0`.

Comment: `UINT8` is too small for `cbuf_length` (it can only store 0 - 255).

Comment: thanks chux, i didn't know that (UINT8)255++ would go back to 0

Comment: thanks Sister Fister, so basically there are 256 values in UINT8, but you can't use 1 of them, because its used as the empty flag in this situation. got it! good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is in the type of `cbuf_length` — after 255, it will overflow to 0. Defining it as a larger type (`UINT16` or even just `unsigned`) will fix it.

Other than that, it's perfectly valid and understandable code. You might want to return something from that function, though — some boolean result telling the caller whether the value was appended successfully or not.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's some issues with your code.

`UINT8` is not a standard type, I suspect it's a Microsoft type. Unless you have a good reason, [use `uint8_t` from stdint.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h).

Second, `cbuf_length < CBUF_SIZE` is always true because `uint8_t` can't store higher than 255.

```
test.c:10:21: warning: comparison of constant 256 with expression of type 'uint8_t'
      (aka 'unsigned char') is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
    if (cbuf_length < CBUF_SIZE) { 
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
```

---

More important, global variables and constants should be avoided. They create complexity, limit you to a single instance, cause problems with concurrency. It's not always clear which global variables must be updated together. It's also not immediately clear what functions affect what data.

Instead, consider using a struct.

For array sizes use `size_t` to avoid exactly the sort of bug you have where the size of the array is larger than the capacity of your type. `size_t` is the type for storing, you guessed it, sizes! It will always be large enough.

Finally, don't forget error handling. Like when your buffer can hold no more elements. In this case I have the append function return a boolean which can be checked to see if the append succeeded. (I've been sloppy in a few other places, like not checking `malloc`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t *buf;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} cbuf;

cbuf *cbuf_new( size_t capacity ) {
    cbuf *self = malloc( sizeof(cbuf) );

    self->size = 0;
    self->capacity = capacity;
    self->buf = malloc( capacity * sizeof(uint8_t) );

    return self;
}

bool cbuf_append( cbuf *self, char c) {
    // Get the error check out of the way early.
    if( self->size >= self->capacity ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Don't forget to cast signed char to uint8_t.
    self->buf[self->size] = (uint8_t)c;
    self->size++;

    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    cbuf *buf = cbuf_new(2);

    cbuf_append(buf, 'f');  // true
    cbuf_append(buf, 'o');  // true
    cbuf_append(buf, 'o');  // false

    // Prints 'fo'
    for( size_t i = 0; i < buf->size; i++ ) {
        printf("%c", buf->buf[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

All the information about the buffer is collected together in a single struct. Now it's immediately clear that `cbuf_append` works on `buf`. You can have multiple buffers if you wish.

---

If you really want a statically allocated buffer, a slight modification gives you optional control of the memory allocation.

```
cbuf *cbuf_new_from_buf( uint8_t *buf, size_t capacity ) {
    cbuf *self = malloc( sizeof(cbuf) );
    self->size = 0;
    self->capacity = capacity;
    self->buf = buf;

    bzero( self->buf, self->capacity );

    return self;
}

cbuf *cbuf_new( size_t capacity ) {
    return cbuf_new_from_buf(
        malloc( capacity * sizeof(uint8_t) ),
        capacity
    );
}
```

Now you can still use `cbuf_new()` to let it take care of memory allocation for you. Or you can use `cbuf_new_from_buf()` to use an existing buffer you've already allocated.

```
uint8_t mybuf[2];
cbuf *buf = cbuf_new_from_buf(mybuf, sizeof(mybuf));
```

---

## But you shouldn't be writing your own buffers!

This is all fine for a learning exercise. But in production if all you want is a sized array you can append to, don't write a bunch of code that you'll (or somebody else) will have to document and maintain and test and fix and add features to. Use an existing library. Like [GLib's GArray type](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html). It does what you want and more.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    // Start with a size 2 buffer, it will grow as needed.
    GArray *buf = g_array_sized_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof(uint8_t), 2);

    uint8_t c = 'f';
    g_array_append_val(buf, c);
    c = 'o';
    g_array_append_val(buf, c);
    c = 'o';
    g_array_append_val(buf, c); // It will grow the buffer.

    for( guint i = 0; i < buf->len; i++ ) {
        printf("%c", g_array_index(buf, uint8_t, i));
    }
    puts("");
}
```

While GArray has some quirks, like not being able to append literals, it's well documented, powerful, and fast. That means you can spend your time on the real code, not basic data structures.

Even better, because the array will grow if necessary there's no chance of a buffer overflow and no need to check if the append succeeded. Your original concern about the buffer size is eliminated, the buffer will just grow as necessary.

Comment: The only caution regarding `glib` on systems with limited memory is `glib` can consume quite a bit just in its initialization and is notably liberal with initial allocations. That's not a bad thing, it may just be a surprise for someone working on an embedded system or on something with little memory (like a raspberry, etc.).

Comment: In super high speed silicon pipes where thermal considerations are required, a static buffer may be suitable.

Comment: some systems use types.h  instead
 
#ifndef _TYPES_H_
#define _TYPES_H_

typedef unsigned long  UINT32;
typedef unsigned short UINT16;
typedef unsigned char  UINT8;

typedef signed long    INT32;
typedef signed short   INT16;
typedef signed char    INT8;

typedef unsigned char  BOOL;

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

#endif

Comment: @hamish `types.h` is not portable and POSIX `sys/types.h` doesn't define `UINT8`. Unless you have a specific reason otherwise, if there's a standards compliant option it's better to use it for portability and readability. If you're working on super high speed silicon pipes with thermal considerations or a tightly memory constrained system that's a very special case and would be useful context to add to your question. Otherwise, use good practices. While GLib might not be appropriate, you can use something like my struct code with a static buffer, or even static struct, if you need to.